# Button Command not finding Binded ViewModel using rg.plugin.popup

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, popup

the issue appears when trying to bind the properties of the view to any source created on ViewModel, an example is the label's Text property<-binding->test(below on code) not works, but Text property of Button i make a bind to another object sended to this viewModel and work's normally. I just would like to understand why the Binding is not working as usual.
 Here's the code.

XAML.cs

```
public PopupView(Func<bool> metodo, Tarefa tarefa)
{
    BindingContext = new ViewModels.Popups.PopupViewModel(metodo, tarefa);
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

XAML

```
<pages:PopupPage 
         xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="Taskinho.Views.Popups.PopupView"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding test}" />
        <Button Text="{Binding tarefa.TarefaTitulo}" Command="{Binding Confirmar}" />
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

ViewModel

```
//Property
private Tarefa _Tarefa;
public Tarefa tarefa
{
    get { return _Tarefa; }
    set { _Tarefa = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Tarefa");
    }
}
//another property
public string test = "Test Name";


//Constructor
public PopupViewModel(Func<bool> metodoParam, Tarefa TarefaParam)
{            
    this.tarefa = new Tarefa();
    ExecutarCommand = new Command(ExecutarAction);
}

//The binded Command(Not finded by the binding)
public Command ExecutarCommand
{
    get;
    set;
}
//Action of Command
void ExecutarAction()
{
    //do something
}
```

I tried to use Path="" and Source="" on Button binding but i don't know how to use for this situation.

Project Link [Open/Public on Git](https://github.com/lemarcelo/Taskinho)

Thank's

Comment: If my reply solved your issue, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the label's Text property<-binding->test(below on code) not works, but Text property of Button i make a bind to another object sended to this viewModel and work's normally. I just would like to understand why the Binding is not working as usual

Firstly, you can only bind property, not field. replace your code:

```
 private string _test;
    public string test
    {
        get { return _test; }
        set
        {
            _test = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("test");
        }
    }   
    public PopupViewModel(Func<bool> metodoParam, Tarefa TarefaParam)
    {
        this.tarefa = new Tarefa();
        ExecutarCommand = new Command(ExecutarAction);
        test = "this is test!";
    }
```

About Path="" and Source="", I do one sample for you.

Here is viewmodel class:

```
public class viewmodel1: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _test;
    public string test
    {
        get
        {
            return _test;
        }
        set
        {
            _test = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("test");
        }
    }
    public  Command command1 { get; set; }

    public viewmodel1()
    {
        test = "this is test!";
        command1 = new Command(method1);
    }

    private void method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("this is test!!!!!!!");
    }

  
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }


}
```

Here is the view:

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="demo2.simplecontrol.Page18"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:model="clr-namespace:demo2.simplecontrol">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <model:viewmodel1 x:Name="data1" />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Text="{Binding Path=test, Source={x:Reference data1}}"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        <Button Command="{Binding Path=command1, Source={x:Reference data1}}" Text="click1" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

More detailed information, you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-path

Comment: Yeeah!!, it's solved now!! Thank you so much! I just tried using the same code you showed me.
 Changing the:
`<Content.BindingContext> `
by 
`<pages: PopupPage.BindingContext>`
And adding this in XAML:
1-     `xmlns:Page="clr-namespace:Taskinho.ViewModels.Popups"` 
2-     `<Page:PopupViewModel />`
 Used to pass the ViewModel as BindingContext.